# Using Javascript variables within a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using JQuery to output a link to my webpage. Part of the link is dynamic, and I am having trouble using variables and text together. The variable just gets treated as text. What am I doing wrong?

My Jquery:

```
var new_collection_id= 1;
var new_collection_title= 'This is a title';

.html('<a href="collection.php?id=1&collection=new_collection_id">     
new_collection_title </a>')
```

Comment: How the script should know that those are variables? _String Concatenation_.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you done any research?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use string concatenation.

```
.html('<a href="collection.php?id=1&collection=' + new_collection_id 
     + '">' +  new_collection_title + '</a>')
```

Ideally I would suggest you to use

```
.html( $('<a></a>')
      .text(new_collection_title)
      .attr('href', 'collection.php?id=1&collection=' + new_collection_id)
    )
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/WFusC/)

Comment: @plalx While that's needed in general, you can do without it when you know the ID is always a number.

Comment: @Barmar I know, however there's no way to tell here... well now it seems there is since the OP modified the question ;)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [concatenation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp).

```
.html('<a href="collection.php?id=1&collection=' + new_collection_id + '">' + new_collection_title + ' </a>')
```